# Selenium IDE Chrome extension does not select a date from a date picker

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am new to Selenium IDE. I recorded the steps to register to this test application http://91.250.80.22:8085/#/auth/register/one  using the Selemium IDE Chrome extension and when I run the test, the date is not selected. How can I make Selenium IDE to open the date picker and select the date?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can go for using simple sendkeys as date instead of using any special date picker. Just click on the element first and use simple sendkeys for entering the date.

```
WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.id("input-geburtsdatum"));
we.click();
we.sendKeys("11291993");
```

Don't include '/' in send keys as they are not recognized. The above code should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, but as I said I am using the Chrome extension.
Where can I go to enter the codes above?